# Selector has different behavior on Android SDK 2.1 and 4.2.2

Tags: android, xml, selector

I have a layout with a `GridView`.

Each item in the `Gridview` is a `LinearLayout` that implements the `Checkable interface`.

All works OK. But it only show correctly in SDK 4.2.2

**SDK 4.2.2**

[image]

**SDK 2.1**

[image]

The black background should not be shown.

**GridView code**

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gvBirds"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:verticalSpacing="4dp"
    android:layout_margin="32dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"           
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:listSelector="@color/transparent">
</GridView>
```

**GridView item code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<pt.rogerioamaral.ByMAP.CheckableLinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridItemLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/grid_item_selector">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lbBirdName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="nome grande"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/main_gradient_end" 
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/falcao_small"
        android:background="@drawable/main_grid_background"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

</pt.rogerioamaral.ByMAP.CheckableLinearLayout>
```

**Selector code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_checked="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/main_gradient_end"/>
            <corners android:radius="20dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:color="@color/main_gradient_end"
                android:width="3dp"/>
            <corners android:radius="20dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/main_gradient_end"/>
            <corners android:radius="20dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@color/transparent"/>
</selector>
```

**colors.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <color name="main_gradient_start">#454444</color>
    <color name="main_gradient_end">#BAB8B9</color>
    <color name="transparent">#00000000</color>
</resources>
```

What I have to do to have the same behavior in both situations?

Comment: 2.1 is pretty much non existant now a days, I wouldn't even bother with it unless you have a specific reason to do so.

Google doesnt even show it anymore in their OS Distribution Chart.

http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html?utm_content=buffer07ca2&utm_source=buffer&utm_medium=twitter&utm_campaign=Buffer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to add `<solid>` atributte with `color="@color/transparent"` on `state_checked="true"`

```
<item android:state_checked="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/transparent"/>
        <stroke android:color="@color/main_gradient_end"
            android:width="3dp"/>
        <corners android:radius="20dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your GridView XML android:listSelector(int) is actually the selected item. It doesn't error because your @color/transparent is (int)0x00000000.

I'm pretty sure the difference in the background is due to a change in the default background color between the SDKs.

Hopefully these two changes will fix it. (note the first is just for clarity)

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gvBirds"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:verticalSpacing="4dp"
    android:layout_margin="32dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"           
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:listSelector="0"> <!-- selects the first item in the list, changed for clarity -->
</GridView> 



<item android:state_checked="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:color="@color/main_gradient_end"
                android:background="@color/transparent"
                android:width="3dp"/> <!-- added to set background color to transparent -->
            <corners android:radius="20dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
```

Comment: android:background on `<stroke>` don't work. But you put me on the right direction. See my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Bleah. I meant to add the solid. Sorry about that, but happy to see you got the right direction inspite of my error.